# pip install PySide fails

Tags: pyqt, pip, pyside, python-3.4

I am using both Python 2 and Python 3. I am trying to make `pylab` variation of `ipython` work on Python 3 (as it works well enough on Python 2).

After failing to install `PyQt4`, I have tried installing `PySide` install, using the following `pip` command:

```
sudo pip -vvv install --upgrade pyside
```

It took a while. My computer got fairly hot, also. But after reaching 100%, the installation failed with the following error message:

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside/setup.py", line 1001, in <module>
            ext_package = 'PySide',
          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside/setup.py", line 245, in run
            raise RuntimeError("Can't find '%s'" % (filename,))
        RuntimeError: Can't find '/usr/bin/pyside_postinstall.py'

        ----------------------------------------
    Cleaning up...
      Removing source in /tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside                                                                                                    [85/929]
    Command "/usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__fil
    e__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1z4uq1n8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compi
    le" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside
    Exception information:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
        root=options.root_path,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
        **kwargs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 862, in install
        show_stdout=False,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 732, in call_subprocess
        % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
    pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside/setup.py';exec(compile(get
    attr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1z4uq1n8-record/install-record.txt --single-
    version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-o8v5e0ej/pyside
```

So all in all, it did not help me with `pylab`. Running `ipython --pylab` raises

```
ImportError: libpyside.cpython-34m.so.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is a result of the line

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, __version__, __version_info__
```

Have I done something wrong?

---

My system info:

- Python 3.4.0
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-40-generic

Comment: Latest pyside version (not relased yet) does not require the post-install script (pyside_postinstall.py). Pleae try to install pyside by folowing the instructions from install guide http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/building/linux.html#building-pyside-distribution-from-a-git-repository

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure this is a proper answer to my question, as it does not really solve the problem with `pip`, but I have succeeded in solving the `pylab` issue on my machine, and this is what I've done:

- I've purged (via `aptitude`) **both** `python3-pyqt4` and `python3-pyqt5`
- I've uninstalled (via `pip`) `python` `pyside`
- I've installed (via `aptitude`) `python3-pyside`

Now `ipython --pylab` works (with Python 3.4.0).